# Are there any APIs for opening and playing .swf files in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, ipad, api, macos

I need to open a .swf file for a C++ iPad application on my mac, but I can't find any APIs for doing so.

Comment: That's an Adobe Flash file.  That might ring a bell perhaps?  Steve Jobs doesn't like Flash, it is *verboten* on iPad.  But you also mention "mac", not sure what the real question might be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe VideoLAN Client (VLC) can open/play SWF files.  VLC is an open-source program so check out the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native API support for swf playback on either Mac or iPad as far as I know.
So you would have to use a 3rd party library like [gameswf](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash has an ActiveX control you can import & use.  I use TShockwaveFlash under C++ Builder.  I import the ActiveX control which essentially gives me access to the API for loading & playing SWF files in my application.

Maybe this is of some help to you?  Not sure how this translate into iPAD but thought I'd offer up how I've done it at least on Win32/64 environment.